# How to get data from custom modules in ZOHO CRM API?

Tags: crm, zoho

We've created a custom modules in zoho crm. And while accessing the data using api its working for zoho's predefined moudles and its not working for custom modules.

**Query :** `https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/myCustomModuleName/getRecords?authtoken=myauthtoken&scope=crmapi&newFormat=2&selectColumns=All`

**Error :** Unable to process your request. Please verify whether you have entered proper method name,parameter and parameter values.

Any Idea ?

Comment: I too would like to know the answer to this question. Is it possible to use the API against custom Zoho Modules?

Comment: To anyone looking to achieve this using v2, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63179203/4579271.

Answer (score 2):

Use the getModules method to make sure you are calling the correct module. In my case the module looked like it was named "Clients" in the zoho GUI but it was actually named "Potentials" when it was set up by our marketing team, which I could only see after calling the getModules method:

https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Info/getModules?authtoken=AUTH TOKEN&scope=crmapi

https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/getmodules.html

After I specified the correct module, all of the search and query api methods worked just fine.

Comment: Is there a way to change the name of the module (not the display name)?

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but your api request should look like this:

```
https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/CustomModule1/searchRecords?newFormat=2&authtoken=YOURAPITOKEN&scope=crmapi&criteria=(YOURCRITERIA)
```

The custom module names are always **CustomModule1**, **CustomModule2**, **CustomModule3**, etc.

You can see the name by navigating to *Setup > Modules* and viewing the Module Name column in the *List of Modules*.