# How to search Zoho custom module using API v2?

Tags: zoho

I am using an access token with `ZohoCRM.modules.custom.READ`.

When I send a GET request to `https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Custom/search`, I get the following error.

```
{
    "code": "INVALID_MODULE",
    "details": {},
    "message": "the module name given seems to be invalid",
    "status": "error"
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I define the module I am trying to pull data from (it is called `CustomModule2`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out...

First, needed to go to [https://crm.zoho.com/crm/{org_id}/settings/modules](https://crm.zoho.com/crm/%7Borg_id%7D/settings/modules) to find the actual name of `CustomModule2` which is `Adresses livraison`.

Then, needed to go to [https://crm.zoho.com/crm/{org_id}/settings/api/modules](https://crm.zoho.com/crm/%7Borg_id%7D/settings/api/modules) to find the API name for `Adresses livraison` which is `Adresses_livraison`.

Finally, needed to go to [https://crm.zoho.com/crm/{org_id}/settings/api/modules/CustomModule2?step=FieldsList](https://crm.zoho.com/crm/%7Borg_id%7D/settings/api/modules/CustomModule2?step=FieldsList) to find the API name of the field I wanted to use as a search criteria (it was `Compte`].

The final query using [httpie](https://httpie.org/) is as follows.

```sh
http GET https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Adresses_livraison/search \
Authorization:"Zoho-oauthtoken {access_token}" \
criteria=="(Compte:equals:{account_id})"
```

Zoho is up there in the most awkward developer experiences I have encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for anyone still looking into this, because I noticed that the links aren't always the same, depending on whether it's a sandbox or not, etc. So the steps are:

1. Go to your CRM page/dashboard and click on the Settings (cogwheel icon) on the top-right, next to your account image.
2. A bunch of items in panel boxes open. In the panel named "*Developer Space*" choose **APIs**
3. There it opens a bunch of tabs and sub-tabs and a Dashboard *(As shown on the image below)*. The "**Dashboard**" sub-tab should be selected, all you have to do is switch to the sub-tab "**API-Names**"

[image]